# How to use Android Fragment in flutter

Tags: android, android-fragments, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

In android we have fragment to store data and create data dynamically 
how to handle this issue in flutter for IOS platform?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show research you have done on the topic and what you've tried so far.

Comment: How do you store data in a fragment ? And why ?

Comment: I can build 1 fragment and use it in dynamic data. For example load multiple data in fragment and update data dynamically in that, and user can go back and see the previous data. There is no lifecycle in fragment.

Comment: State Management is quite different in Flutter compared to Android: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Comment: Can i use state manager for load secondary data on first data and my first data be aproachable with back button?